# Flutter - Navigator.pushReplacement after delay causes Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart

I am experiencing something strange.

When I call Navigator.pushReplacement after a delay, I get this error in the console:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter ( 8437): #0      StatefulElement.state (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4926:44)
E/flutter ( 8437): #1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2542:47)
E/flutter ( 8437): #2      Navigator.pushReplacement (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2103:22)
```

This only happens when I call it after a delay, like this:

```
   Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {

      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MenuScreen()));
      
    });
```

Here is my widget for the MenuScreen:

```
class MenuScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  // const MenuScreen({Key? key, this.selectedIndex = 0}) : super(key: key);
  const MenuScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // final int selectedIndex;

  @override
  State<MenuScreen> createState() => _MenuScreenState();

}

class _MenuScreenState extends State<MenuScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('My Sessions'),),

      body: Container(),
      // drawer: DrawerWidget() ,

    );
  }
}
```

However, if I call this on the click of a button, there is no error.

Also, if I use Navigator.push, it doesn't happen.

Why would this be?

Here is the code for my splash screen:

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}



class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

  String token = '';

  @override
  void initState() {

    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((pref) {
      String token = pref.getString('token') ?? '';
      setState(() {
        this.token = token;
      });
    });

    super.initState();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {

      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MenuScreen()));

    });
   


    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xff193C68),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
                'assets/strivright_logo.png',
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75),
            SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2),

            const CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white)),


          ],
        ),
      ),


    );



  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide full widget that will reproduce this issue. More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: There should be no problem for your code to be applied to simple case.

Comment: Added code to question